# How to set shape/format of a target(y) array for multiple output regression in Keras?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 4 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[115.,  23.,  37.,  27.,  60.,  35.,  77.,  50., 104., 134.,  99.,
         59.,  52., 179.,  77.,  85.],
       [495., 457., 601., 602., 586., 549., 558., 627., 552., 500., 524.,
        587....
```

This is the error I am getting, when I run the **following code**:

```
inp = Input((480,640,3))
x = Dense(13, activation = 'relu')(inp)
out1 = Dense(1 , activation = 'linear')(x)
out2 = Dense(1 , activation = 'linear')(x)
out3 = Dense(1 , activation = 'linear')(x)
out4 = Dense(1 , activation = 'linear')(x)
model = Model(inp , [out1,out2,out3,out4])
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit_generator(generator = imageLoader(train_can , 16) , steps_per_epoch = 14000/16 , epochs = 1)
```

The **imageLoader** function is as follows:

```
def imageLoader(files, batch_size = 16):

   L = len(files)

#this line is just to make the generator infinite, keras needs that    
   while True:

     batch_start = 0
     batch_end = batch_size

     while batch_start < L:
        limit = min(batch_end, L)
        X = someMethodToLoadImages(files[batch_start:limit])
        Y = rearrange(train_y[batch_start:limit])

        yield (X,Y) #a tuple with two numpy arrays with batch_size samples     

        batch_start += batch_size   
        batch_end += batch_size
```

The function **someMethodToLoadImages** is as follows:

```
def someMethodToLoadImages(files ):
    images =  np.empty((0,480,640,3) , float)
    for file in files:
         img =  image.load_img(os.path.join("G:/flipkart/images" , file ) ) #no target size required as all images are of same size
         images = np.append(images ,  image.img_to_array(img).reshape(1,480,640,3), axis = 0)
    return images/255.0
```

The function **rearrange** is as follows:

```
def rearrange(arr):
   length = arr.shape[0]
   arr_ = np.ones((4,length))
   for i,sample in enumerate(arr):
       for index,number in enumerate(sample):
            arr_[index,i] = number
   return arr_
```

How to solve this problem? I have checked out similar questions on stack, but I am still not able to get a solution.

----------------------------------------**UPDATE**-------------------------------

```
inp = Input((480,640,3))
#x = Dense(13, activation = 'relu')(inp)
x = Conv2D(filters = 10, kernel_size = (3,3), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', data_format=None, dilation_rate=(1, 1), activation=None, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None)(inp)
x1 = Flatten()(x)
out1 = Dense(1 , activation = 'linear')(x1)
out2 = Dense(1 , activation = 'linear')(x1)
out3 = Dense(1 , activation = 'linear')(x1)
out4 = Dense(1 , activation = 'linear')(x1)

model = Model(inp , [out1,out2,out3,out4])
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

print(model.summary())
```

This is the **model summary:**

[image: Model Summary]

On running this:

```
model.fit_generator(generator = imageLoader(train_can , 16) , steps_per_epoch = 14000/16 , epochs = 1)
```

I got:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 4 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[115.,  23.,  37.,  27.,  60.,  35.,  77.,  50., 104., 134.,  99.,
     59.,  52., 179.,  77.,  85.],
   [495., 457., 601., 602., 586., 549., 558., 627., 552., 500., 524.,
    587....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model has four outputs, so you must have the groundtruth labels also as a python list of four elements. Instead, you return a single numpy array.
See [this](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models) for an example of multiple input/output models.

Answer (score 1):

Have you called `model.summary()` to see what is the output shape of your 4 output layers? In an up-to-date Keras version it will be `(None, 480, 640, 1)` for each of your 4 output layers (`None` is the batch size). This is likely not what you want. From looking at how you generate your `Y`-values, I'm assuming you want to simply have `(None, 1)` instead.

However, whatever the actual output shape is that you want to have, to answer your question: `Y` has to be an *ordinary* list of size 4 (because you have 4 output layers), where each element of this list must be a numpy array whose shape perfectly matches the output shape of the corresponding output layer. In your case, all output layers have the same shape. So, for the given `model` as you present it in your question

```
Y = [np.ones((batch_size, 480, 640, 1)), np.ones((batch_size, 480, 640, 1)), np.ones((batch_size, 480, 640, 1)), np.ones((batch_size, 480, 640, 1))]
```

would be a valid return value of your `rearrange` function. The first entry of this list will be applied to the output of `out1`, the second one to `out2`, etc.

If my guess is correct and you actually want to have 4 output shapes of `(None, 1)`, then first (of course) you have to redesign your model to actually have these output shapes. And then

```
Y = [np.ones((batch_size, 1)), np.ones((batch_size, 1)), np.ones((batch_size, 1)), np.ones((batch_size, 1))]
```

would be what you need.

Note, an ordinary list is only necessary, if the output layers have different output shapes. In this particular example, however, all of your output shapes are the same, so instead of an ordinary list you could also return `Y = np.ones((4, batch_size, 1))`. As this is almost exactly what you are currently doing (all you need is call `reshape((4, batch_size, 1))` to add the missing last dimension), I'm very confident that you just misunderstood how `Dense` layers work. They only change the last dimension of the input tensor. The [Flatten](https://keras.io/layers/core/) layer is the easiest way to get a one-dimensional tensor (actually two-dimensional if you count in the batch size). Again, `model.summary()` is your friend.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I removed the Dense layer and replaced it with a Conv2D layer but still I get the same error. Please check out the update in my post.

Comment: @FarazGerrardJamal oh, my bad. The last dimension will always stay. Have corrected my answer.